# When to create an S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm setting up my client with a system that allows users to upload a video or two. These videos will be stored on Amazon S3, which I've not used before. I'm unsure about buckets, and what they represent. Do you think I would have a single bucket for my application, a bucket per user or a bucket per file?

If I were to just have the one bucket, presumably I'd have to have really long, illogical file names to prevent a file name clash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no limit to the amount of objects you can store in a bucket, so generally you would have a single bucket per application, or even across multiple applications. Bucket names have to be globally unique across S3 so it would certainly be impossible to manage a bucket per object. A bucket per user would also be difficult if you had more than a handful of users.

For more background on buckets you can try reading [Working with Amazon S3 Buckets](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html)

Your application should generate unique keys for objects you are adding to the bucket. Try and avoid numeric ascending ids, as these are considered inefficient. Simply reversing a numeric id can usually make an effective object key. See [Amazon S3 Performance Tips & Tricks](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/amazon-s3-performance-tips-tricks-seattle-hiring-event.html) for a more detailed explanation.